# IDAPython: Get struct id defined at an address

Tags: idapython

Spotted an interesting problem when trying to determine which type of structure (since `isStruct(getFlags(ea))` returns `True`) is defined at the given address in the DB. Reading through `idc.py` didn't help much.

- Define a `struct` in the "structures" window.
- It gets assigned a `struct` ID, so, it can be accessed from IDC/Python scripts.
- Now, define a `struct` variable somewhere in e.g. the `.data` section.

A solid example:

```
# Some Python code
strid = idaapi.get_struc_id('_s__RTTIClassHierarchyDescriptor')
size = idaapi.get_struc_size(strid)
idaapi.doStruct(ea, size, strid)
```

How, knowing the `ea`, do I get the `strid` value ?

Comment: What is your question ? What problem did you spot ?

Comment: I didn't get what is the problem ?!?

Comment: Updated the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This works for me:

```
ea=here()
ti = idaapi.opinfo_t()
f = idc.GetFlags(ea)
if idaapi.get_opinfo(ea, 0, f, ti):
   print ("tid=%08x - %s" % (ti.tid, idaapi.get_struc_name(ti.tid)))
```

So `ti.tid` then contains the strid.

Comment: Confirmed working. Likely because IDA treats the structure variable as an "operand" of some "instruction".

Comment: Sorry, there is 1 day timeout for bounties. :-(

Comment: Looks like the bounty is still open.
https://imgur.com/d0NYZSq.jpg

Comment: Can't award earlier than 24h after starting the bounty, it seems. :-( Will do so ASAP.

Comment: There we go, awarded! :-)

Comment: Wow. Just Wow. The IDA API. Have to use 5 different namespaces to create a variable at an address, set its type, set its name, get its name, get its type, determine if it's one of built-in types or a user-defined type, get type name.

Comment: Thanks, Willem, you're a savior, I couldn't figure out how to do it. It doesn't work anymore, needed to update for the newer API.

Answer (score 3):

in IDC the following works, so I'm not sure if you can use the same functions from Python

```
auto type;
auto ea;

ea = 0x8F84C37C;
Message("isStruct: %d\n", isStruct(GetFlags(ea)));
type = GetTinfo(ea);
Message("firstattr: %s\n", firstattr(type));
Message("getattr: %d\n", getattr(type,"typid"));
```

outputting:

```
isStruct: 1
firstattr: typid
getattr: 52541
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me from Python... even if using IDC adapter funcs from idc.py. To be fair, copying your snippet into an IDC script and executing it indeed works. :-)  

`Python>print idc.isStruct(idc.GetFlags(0x561114))
True
Python>print idc.GetTinfo(0x561114)
None
Python>print idc.GetType(0x561114)
None`
Sorry for this unreadable blob, I seem unable to insert line breaks in comments, but you probably get the idea of what's returned.

Comment: That seems broken that the Python IDC wrapper for GetTinfo gets different results.

Comment: idc.GetTinfo appears to just be calling idaapi.idc_get_type_raw(ea), but it's strange that it's failing. looking at swig/typeinf.i idc_get_type_raw appears to call get_tinfo so I'd expect it to work.

Comment: Oddly enough:
`Python>tif = idaapi.tinfo_t()
Python>print tif
<idaapi.tinfo_t; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'tinfo_t *' at 0x02A5BFB0> >
Python>print idaapi.get_tinfo2(0x561114, tif)
False`
and
`Python>tp = idaapi.qtype()
Python>flags = idaapi.qtype()
Python>print idaapi.get_tinfo(0x561114, tp, flags)
False`
so either those are broken, or I am doing it wrong (together with idapython, apparently).

Answer (score 1):

Updated version of @Willem Hengeveld answer for IDA 7.4 API:

```
address=0x14001D020
struct_id = idaapi.opinfo_t()
flags = ida_bytes.get_flags(address)
if ida_bytes.get_opinfo(struct_id, address, 0, flags):
    struct_name = ida_struct.get_struc_name(struct_id.tid)
    print (f"tid=0x{struct_id.tid:08x} - {struct_name}")
```