# How to create and change variables at address in IDA Python?

Tags: ida, idapython

I'd like to be able to create and change global variables at addresses with IDA Python: if variable doesn't exist, create it, if it exists, change it, set its name, undefine it.

For structs, there's [`idc.add_struc`](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/idc.html#idc.add_struc), [`idc.add_struc_member`](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/idc.html#idc.add_struc_member), [`idc.set_member_type`](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/idc.html#idc.set_member_type), [`idc.set_member_name`](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/idc.html#idc.set_member_name), [`idc.del_struc`](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/idc.html#idc.del_struc), [`idc.del_struc_member`](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/idc.html#idc.del_struc_member).

There's [`idc.set_name`](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/idc.html#idc.set_name) to set a name at address and [`ida_bytes.get_flags`](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/ida_bytes.html#ida_bytes.get_flags) function to get flags, but I can't find a respective function such as `set_flags` or `set_type` to change global variable type at address. So to set variable type to dword, I'd do something like `ida_bytes.set_flags(0x14001D01C, ida_bytes.dword_flag())`, and to set it to structure type, I'd like to do something like `ida_bytes.set_flags(0x14001D01C, ida_bytes.stru_flag(), ida_struct.get_struc_id("MyStructName"))`

I scrolled through idaapi, ida_bytes, idc, ida_struct and ida_typeinf documentation. I also searched for `set_`, `_flag`, `_type` and other in the search box on the hex-rays documentation website, and also manually with Ctrl+F in the pages for namespaces above, but couldn't find functions to set flags at address.

Answer (score 3):

The methods I was looking for are:

- [`ida_bytes.create_data`](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/ida_bytes.html#ida_bytes.create_data) (and other `create_` variations, such as
  [`create_byte`](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/ida_bytes.html#ida_bytes.create_byte)) to create and change type of variables.
- [`ida_bytes.del_items`](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/ida_bytes.html#ida_bytes.del_items) to undefine variables.
- [`idc.set_name`](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/idc.html#idc.set_name) or [`ida_name.set_name`](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/ida_name.html#ida_name.set_name) to define, change and undefine names of variables.

To get the name of the variable at address, use [`idc.get_name`](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/idc.html#idc.get_namehttps://www.hex-rays.com/wp-content/static/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/idc.html#idc.get_name).

To get the type of the variable at address, first retreive the flags with [`ida_bytes.get_flags`](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/ida_bytes.html#ida_bytes.get_flags). Then to get its actual type you can use functions, such as [`idc.is_byte`](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/idc.html#idc.is_byte) to determine if it's a byte, or [`idc.is_struct`](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/idc.html#idc.is_struct) to determine if it's a struct. Then, if it's a struct, to determine specific type of a struct, use `idaapi.get_opinfo(struct_id_buffer, ea, 0, flags)` ([example](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/30000/33592)).

For structs, there's [`idc.add_struc`](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/idc.html#idc.add_struc), [`idc.add_struc_member`](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/idc.html#idc.add_struc_member), [`idc.set_member_type`](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/idc.html#idc.set_member_type), [`idc.set_member_name`](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/idc.html#idc.set_member_name), [`idc.del_struc`](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/idc.html#idc.del_struc), [`idc.del_struc_member`](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/idc.html#idc.del_struc_member).